# how to databind datagridview with datatable (C#)

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, desktop-application

I want to bind datagridview in windows application with dynamically changed datatable.

I have windows form with two textboxes, one for connection string with sql server and the other for sql query string. I just want to display data in datagridview in order to see data. I don't need anything fancy, just to read result of sql query.

Thanks in advance!

DP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the `DataTable` to the `Datasource` property of the DataGridView.

Comment: I did that, but I got an empty datagridview even if dataTable has 1 row. :(

Comment: Did you disable `AutoGenerateColumns` maybe?

Comment: Thanks leppie. I have the same issue but after done autogeneratedcolumn = true resolved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the datatable just do the following:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = myDataTable;
myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

That should be all you need to do.